# How to put params from database table into CSS style

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'd like to define parameters of CSS style in database tabele (MySQL) and use them for example to stylink menu. I know that it is possible if we put variable into style like this:

```
<div id="content-inner" style="<?php echo $this->var['color'] ;?>">
```

but maybe anyone know better way ?

Comment: imo the way you are suggesting is a good way, another way would be to generate the entire css file through php (load a style.css.php or something like that). but that is pretty much the same. might be cleaner though

Comment: The question is if it is a good way to styling directly in html line ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a database (MySQL) to perform a task like this... This creates a unnecessary load on your web-server as well as db-server and just eats up more you memory for no reason. You should use JavaScript and a statically declared JSON object containing the values. If your confused of what I mean let me know and I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
<?php echo $this->var['color'] ;?>
```

you can write

```
<?= $this->var['color'] ?>
```

for more minified, faster, cleaner and easier to read code

Answer (score 0):

in your main page use

```
<style type="text/css">
.custom_class_name{
<?php echo $this->var['color'] ;?>
}
</style>
```

then use this custom_class_name what ever you want in the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JavaScript to preform a task like this, using a database just creates unnecessary load on your web/database servers eating up your memory.

If it's a single property you should update like so:

//SINGLE CSS CHANGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
#target{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;    
}
</style>
<script>
function colorChange(){
    var target = document.getElementById("target"); 
    target.setAttribute("style", "background:blue;");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="colorChange();">Click Me</button>
    <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If it's multiple property changes you should use a id/class like so:

//MULTIPLE CSS CHANGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.body{
    margin: 0 !important;
}
#target1{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;    
}
#target2{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;   
}
</style>
<script>
function colorChange(){
    var target = document.getElementById("target1");    
    target.setAttribute("id", "target2");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="colorChange();">Click Me</button>
    <div id="target1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```